# Roboform asks to save password

Tags: javascript, angular, browser-extension

I perform authentication with **passport.js**. However after session is created, after each AJAX request **RoboForm** asks to save password. Can't figure out what could be the reason.

### Here are the headers:

#### Request Headers

Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:connect.sid=s%3AjvQRBQY...
Host:localhost:3000
If-None-Match:W/"140-3603896551"
Referer:http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0

#### Response Headers

Connection:keep-alive
Date:Wed, 26 Apr 2017 11:42:51 GMT
ETag:W/"140-3603896551"
X-Powered-By:Express

### Example of serverside code:

```
app.get('/users', function(req,res) {
  if(typeof req.user == 'undefined'){
    res.status(403).end();return;
  }

  users.get(function(error,results){
    if(error !== null){
      res.json({"error":"Error getting users"})
    }else {
      res.json(results);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This question is unclear

Comment: @DanGreen-Leipciger When you login to a website, browser or RoboForm(if installed) asks if password should be stored. With my app after user loggs in each time ajax request is sent to the server, RoboForm asks to store the password. By the way this happens only if I send get request **with angular2 Http, not jQuery $.get()**

Comment: @DanGreen-Leipciger I've added serverside code to question

Comment: I think this is a client side problem (Angular2). If you are getting one behaviour with angular2 http and jQuery $.get()

Comment: @DanGreen-Leipciger definitely, RoboForm triggers if I click a link which does not point anywhere

Comment: You should change the question tags.  Your question as it is written will not attract the people who can answer your question.

Comment: @DanGreen-Leipciger thanks, changed, but there is no roboform tag

Comment: @Maxim - please put the code in jsbin so we can replicate the error.

Comment: @StevenWinston sorry, that's problematic to me

Answer (score 1):

This strikes me as a client-side problem. Roboform is triggered by an action on the client so in order to help more it would be good to see your Angular controller/service code.

Thanks!

Comment: Here is loogin code: `var options:Object = {"headers":{"Content-Type": "application/json"}};
    this.http.post(
      '/login',
      JSON.stringify(this.login_info), options).map(res => res.json()).subscribe((res) => this.loginCallback(res));`

Comment: Do you have all your code in a github repo?
Looking at this small fragment of a service it is not possible to tell where any possible bug could be.

Comment: Here I have created github repo: https://github.com/max-funeasylearn/promo-codes.